# React/Redux not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm just starting in redux and I want to include it on my existing app. What I want to do is to `store` my login response for me to use the user details on other page.

**LandingPage.js**

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

function LandingPage(){
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const authLogin = async()=>{
  const response = await axios.get('/api',)
  let responseValue = response.data.success
  if(responseValue === true) {
     const parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data.resp)
     dispatch({
       type: 'SAVE_AUTH',
       payload: {
         isLoggedIn: responseValue,
         username: parsedData.data.user.userName,
         token: parsedData.data.token
       }
     })
  }
useEffect(() => {
authLogin();
  }, [])
return (
<div>
  <label>Authenticating....</label>
  <Login1 /> //updated based on @LindaPaiste's answer
</div>
export default LandingPage;
```

**MainLanding.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Login1 from './Login1'
function MainLanding(){
return(
    <div>
        <h1>User Login Details</h1>
        <Login1 /> //Nothing hapens here
    </div>
)
}
export default MainLanding;
```

**Login1.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import LoginDetailsx from './LoginDetailsx'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
function Login1(){
const userLoginDetails = useSelector((state) => state.loginDetails)
console.log('userLoginDetails',userLoginDetails)
return(
    <div>
        <h2>Login Details</h2>
        <LoginDetailsx isLogin={userLoginDetails.isLoggedIn} username={userLoginDetails.username} token={userLoginDetails.token}/>
        })}
        
    </div>
)}
export default Login1;
```

**loginDetailsReducer.js**

```
const initialState = [
{
    isLoggedIn: false,
    
}];

const loginDetailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
const { type, payload } = action;
console.log('typex',type)
console.log('payloadx',payload)

switch(type){
    case "SAVE_AUTH":
        alert('dasdasd')
        return payload;
    case "LOGOUT_AUTH":
        return initialState
    default:
        return state;
}
}
export default loginDetailsReducer;
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import loginDetailsReducer from '../reduxReducers/loginDetailsReducer'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginDetails: loginDetailsReducer
});
export default rootReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../reduxReducers/rootReducer'
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
export default store;
```

**LoginDetailsx.js**

```
import React from 'react'
function LoginDetailsx(props){
return(
    <div>
        <p>Details: isloggedin: {props.isloggedin}, username: {props.username}, token: {props.token}</p>
    </div>
   )
}
export default LoginDetailsx;
```

This is what I'm getting on `MainLanding.js` after successful login.
[image]

and this is what i'm getting on `LandingPage.js` `console.log`
[image]

Comment: I don't see any reason that your `loginDetails` state should be an `array`.  It should only have one user at a time.

Comment: Is `LandingPage` supposed to be a component?  You need to do all of the `async` stuff in a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste, my apologies I'm just following the tutorial that I've watch. I will adjust it later when resolved. as for the `LandingPage` I make it that way (for now), for me to monitor the datas. Since i'm new to react.

Comment: Can I see where you add <Provider /> ?
https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#provider

Comment: The `payload` that you are sending is an object while you are expecting `payload` as an array. Also, are you passing `store` as a prop to your `<App />` component using a `<Provider />` ?

Answer (score 3):

#### State Shape

While not necessarily a *problem*, it really doesn't make sense that the `loginDetails` state should be an `array`.  Only one user should be logged in at a time, so it should just be an object with the user details.  That makes your reducer extremely simple (as always [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) can make it even simpler).

You'll want to add a logout case too.  `isLoggedIn` should be a `boolean` instead of a `string`.  I personally think that `undefined` makes more sense than `''` for `username` and `token` when there is no logged in user but that's up to you.

```
const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    // no username or token when logged out
};

const loginDetailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    switch(type) {
        case "SAVE_AUTH":
            // replace the state with the action payload
            return payload;
        case "LOGOUT_AUTH":
            // revert to initial state
            return initialState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default loginDetailsReducer;
```

#### Logging In

I was going to say that asynchronous actions like API calls need to be done inside a `useEffect` hook in the component.  You can use an empty dependency array to run the effect once when the component is mounted.

```
useEffect(() => {
    authLogin();
}, []);
```

But now I'm looking at your image and it seems like you are executing the action in response to a button click, so that's fine too.

`axios` handles JSON parsing so you should not need to use `JSON.parse()` (unless your API is returning strange data).

```
function MainLanding() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.loginDetails.isLoggedIn);

  // access dispatch function
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // define the function to log in
  const authLogin = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/api");
    const data = response.data;
    if (data.success === true) {
      dispatch({
        type: "SAVE_AUTH",
        payload: {
          isLoggedIn: true,
          username: data.resp.user.userName,
          token: data.resp.data.token
        }
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <h1>User Login Details</h1>
          <Login1 />
        </>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={authLogin}>Log In</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste, my apologies for the confusion, please disregard the button. The button is for my testing only. I'm getting the login/authentication response based on the response of other system. May I ask why the dispatch and the api response was on `MainLanding.js` ? On my current code, it is on the `LandingPage.js`. In addition, upon making the initial state `object` I got an error `Login1.js` that `userLoginDetails.map is not a function`. Thank you

Comment: In addition, I am using `useEffect` I just forgot to put it on the code(updated). As for the `JSON.parse` yes, I need to parse it because my `API` response forced me too hehe. Thank you again. Hope we can resolve this.

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste, it imported the `Login1`  to `LandingPage.js` just like on your example. But what I want to do is to import the state of `Login1` to other components like `MainLanding`, how will I do it? That's why on my posted code, it comes `LandingPage` and `MainLanding` comes separately. Thank you

Comment: Hey, I moved the login into MainLanding because I didn’t know where you were actually rendering < LandingPage/>.  That’s the only reason.  As far as the .map is not a function error, the auth state is not an array anymore.  So instead of map you would just get the username and token directly off the object.

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste, yes I fixed the issue on map. For LandingPage concern, I still put the `dispatch` in LandingPage and I was able to display the response data on the `LandingPage`, but how will I able to use those data on other components like `MainLanding`? Thank you

Comment: I am not understanding the structure of your app and the hierarchy of components.  If you just load `MainLanding` then the login never gets initiated.  If you load `LandingPage` then it works.  https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-snowflake-0g9mz?file=/src/components/LandingPage.tsx

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste, my apologies if you got confused on my structure. `LandingPage` is working but I want to render `Login1` to `MainLanding` but it doesn't rendered. I load `LandingPage` first to get the `response` then access `MainLanding`. Upon checking on `codesandbox` there is an error upon preview of `MainLanding`. Thank you

Comment: I want to make redux value global for me to use it on other component/page or how will I use it

Comment: Right so the redux state is global, but you have to make sure that you visit the page where the state is set before you visit the page where it is used.  I can set something up with react-router.

Comment: Updated with Redirects from react-router https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-user-login-0g9mz?file=/src/components/App.tsx  But you could also just conditionally render a component that executes the effect instead of conditionally rendering a redirect.  Redirecting to "/login" makes more sense if the user actually has to do something on that page.